# IOS anchor link scroll to section not working

Tags: ios, angular, scroll, anchor

I'm facing a bit of an odd issue, I have a site which has anchor section links for navigation such as this:`<a href="#people">People</a> ... <section id="people" ...>`

It is working for me on

- Linux-Chrome
- Android-Chrome
- MacOS-Chrome and safari

But doesn't work on IOS safari or chrome, a colleague has also been able to replicate this issue on IOS.

Interestingly it works fine on Xcode simulators and browserstack.

There are lots of things which could be messing this up but I'm not sure which one any advice?

I am using:
Angular
AOS
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
scroll-behavior: smooth;